# How to make one component height in one grid column adjust with respect to the other two in one single column?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have two grid columns. And first grid columns has two items (div-1 and div-2). The second column has one item (div-3). I want to make `div-3` height adjusted with the change in `div-1` and `div-2`.

So that both columns will have equal height with the following css.

```
<Grid>
<GridItem>
  <Grid>
   <GridItem >
     <SomeComponent className="div-1"/>
   </GridItem>
   <GridItem >
     <SomeComponent className="div-2"/>
   </GridItem>
  </Grid>
</GridItem>
<GridItem >
  <Grid>
   <GridItem>
     <SomeComponent className="div-3"/> 
   </GridItem>
  </Grid>
</GridItem>
</Grid>
```

Current css:

```
.div-1 {
  max-height: 19rem;
  min-height: 6rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.div-3 {
  max-height: 30rem;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I tried using `useRef` in react but got stuck in passing the states among components. Some items need to show scrollbar and I dont want to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic usecase for CSS grid.

It's not react, but it shouldn't be too hard to convert it for your project.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item1">1<br />asdqwe</div>
  <div class="item item2">2</div>
  <div class="item item3">3</div>
</div>
```

And the magic happens in CSS

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* create grid with 2 dynamic columns */
}
.item3 {
  grid-row: 1 / span 30; /* span 30 rows just to be sure the 3rd item really spans all rows */
  grid-column-start: 2; /* set it to show up in the second column */
}
```

JSFiddle with the demo code: https://jsfiddle.net/7vga2yqc/2/

Comment: I want to have the the items scrollable too, the css in question is required.